# Attach tax rate without hardcoding it?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've been a little confused with how Stripe handles tax rates. When creating a user subscription, I have to attach a tax rate depending on the region the user is from.

All the stripe examples describe how to do this using the id of the tax rate. My problem is, that I'm not sure how to retrieve this id dynamically. Currently, I've simply hardcoded the id of the appropriate tax rate. I'd like to do something like:

```
stripe.TaxRate.retrieve(
  jurisdiction: "GERMANY",
)
```

How do you retrieve tax rates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Partwell is, but you'll need to keep your own map of the jurisdictions -> Tax Rate IDs you've created so that you can retrieve the correct one by ID, which is the only way one can be retrieved: https://stripe.com/docs/api/tax_rates/retrieve